# Sitecore Rich Text Editor - Creating tables

Tags: telerik, sitecore, tabular, author

We have tried creating tables and it is a difficult and time consuming task creating a beautifully formatted table in Sitecore RTE. There are many content authors working on the website who need to publish financial reports in Sitecore websites which are mostly in the form of data within tables. They face great difficulty building the table fast, copying and pasting does not work sometimes since the formatting gets all wrong. Also, formatting an already built table is difficult and in most cases these tables are not responsive. We understand that the responsiveness can be taken care of by using CSS but there are limitations there since the HTML is not always uniform (sometimes the authors copy and paste from word or PDF documents).

Please let me know the easiest way to build a responsive table in Sitecore with no to minimal HTML knowledge.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that doesn't require any developer work?

Comment: @Jason: I am looking for a solution which will make authoring tables in Rich Text Editor easier by authors who have minimal to no HTML experience. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can make "developer" level changes, I see two options:

**Create Customisable Renderings**

Given your desire to have the tables responsive and styled well I would create renderings that you can control as a developer. The editors would need to input the data into Sitecore as items and then use a datasource to populate the rendering. If there's a lot of data, you could consider building an importer as it's in a tabulated (organised) format already.

If the styling needs to change, you can either create multiple renderings or use rendering parameters to give the editor options as to how it will look.

**HTML Snippets**

Sitecore allows you create snippets of HTML which can the be inserted into the RTE by the editor. You would need to create the HTML mark-up with styling/CSS and then create a new `Html Editor Snippet` item under `/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default/Snippets` (assuming you're using the default RTE).

The template for the item can be found at `/System/Html Editor Profiles/Html Editor Snippet`.

The downside to this approach is if you make a change to the mark-up in the snippet item it won't be propagated to previous usages. You would have to manually find and amend those cases.

*HTML snippets are really a last resort and not recommended*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Jason! I have one more question. Is there a way for the authors to copy the table from a word document and keep the source formatting in RTE? and just play with the table after that?

Comment: I would advise against that, you usually end up with some really bad HTML mark-up. You'd probably spend more time fixing it than if you were to create it from scratch using a snippet.